# How to send a file in put request in HttpURLConnection as Binary Request and not Form data?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using HTTPURLConnection to send the file in PUT Request.
For this I am using multipart/form-data to upload the file.

```
 URL apiurl= new URL("upload API URL");
                String authString=UserName+":"+UserPwsd;
                String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authString.getBytes());
                notifiApiConn = (HttpsURLConnection) apiurl.openConnection();
                notifiApiConn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                notifiApiConn.setDoOutput(true);
                notifiApiConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedString);
                 notifiApiConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
                File fetchFile=new File("File Name.tgz");
                
                try (
                        OutputStream output = notifiApiConn.getOutputStream();
                        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, charset), true);
                    ) {
                    
                   
                    writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + File_Name+".tgz" + "\"").append(CRLF);
                    writer.append("Content-Type: "+"application/x-gzip").append(CRLF); 
                    
                    writer.append(CRLF).flush();
                    Files.copy(fetchFile.toPath(), output);
                    output.flush(); 
                    writer.append(CRLF).flush();
```

File is getting uploaded and returning 201 Created Response also.

But the user is unable to decompress it at receiver end.From my end I am able to open the file

Business is asking to use Binary instead of form-data to upload the file. Attaching the screenshot for the same.

I want help that how we can send upload the file using this Binary instead of form data the PUT Request in Httpurlconnection.

[image]

Comment: Eh? f you don't want to send it as multipart/form-data, why are you doing exactly that? But there is one issue you may not be aware of: calling `setDoOutput(true)` sets the request method to POST, so you should do that *before* setting it to PUT.

Comment: Actually this is vendor api which is of type PUT. So i am sending the file in via form-data but since vendor is not able to de compress the file so he is recommending to send via binary instead of form-data

Comment: Actually all you have done here is post the non-working POST/`multipart/form-data` code. You have made no apparent attempt to comply with the vendor's request, or to understand my comment. Why you think `multipart/form-data` amounts to PUT is another mystery. It doesn't.

Comment: @user207421... I have posted the code which was all the way working and vendor was able to received the files. Please follow my question where i posted 201 created response. Its just vendor was asking to post it in binary way instead of form data...so i was looking for some guidance.. thanks for pointing the setDoOutput before setting method to PUT.    Also we need to set it to true if we want to send  ie output a request body, like POST or PUT requests. With GET, we dont usually send a body so we dont need it

Comment: I *gave* you some guidance. Change the order of two lines, and remove the code about `multipart/form-data`. And I'm fully aware of what `setDoOutput(true)` does and why you need to call it. I don't know why you're teling me that. And the point of posting the wrong code instead of your attempt at a solution eludes me still.

Comment: @user207421 This is working code and my attempt with form data. I have searched the solution with binary. Unable to find the same.if you can provide me the reference then i can post my attempt with that another approach also. i tried with your recommendation but i require the reference for binary..

Comment: This is working code that is contrary to what the peer requires. It is therefore irrelevant. You are supposed to post your attempt at a solution. And you've been given enough assistance here to get one. I don't see any evidence here that you've tried any of it, and if you have you have not stated the result.  And you don't need a 'reference' for binary transmission. It is the default, which you are disabling by setting `multipart/form-data`, as I've already stated.

Answer (score -2):

Approach from curl could be:-

```
curl --location --request PUT '<endpoint URI>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
--data-binary '@/<file location>'
```

Using REST Assured,

```
given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename", file).body(file)
```

Comment: I think this answer is not a valid answer as he specifically mentioned how to do it with `HttpUrlConnection` object in Java. Maybe you can edit your answer and provide the correct answer in `HttpUrlConnection`